# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status while compiling C++ code with gradle 2.3

Tags: java, c++, gradle, gradlew, javah

Below is the system configuration where I am running my gradle script to compile my c++ code
System Configuration:

> Windows: Server 2012 R2 Standard  System Type: 64-bit Operating System
>   Java jdk1.7.0_40  MinGw x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0 gradle: 2.3 version

Build Script

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'
apply plugin: 'java'
//-- set the group for publishing
group = 'com.truv.analyticsengine'

/**
 * Initializing GAVC settings
 */
def buildProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withInputStream { 
    stream -> buildProperties.load(stream) 
} 
//if jenkins build, add the jenkins build version to the version. Else add snapshot version to the version.
def env = System.getenv()
if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) {
buildProperties.analyticsengineBuildVersion += ".${env["BUILD_NUMBER"]}"
} else {
buildProperties.analyticsengineBuildVersion += "-SNAPSHOT"
}
version = buildProperties.analyticsengineBuildVersion
println "${version}"

//name is set in the settings.gradle file
group = "com.tru.analyticsengine"
version = buildProperties.analyticsengineBuildVersion
println "Building ${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
jar {
   manifest {
       attributes 'Implementation-Title': "${project.name}",
                   'Implementation-Version': "${project.version}",
                   'Implementation-Vendor-Id': "${project.group}"
                  }
}

repositories {
    maven {
      url "http://arti.tru.com:8090/libs-snapshot-local"
    }
     maven {
      url "http://arti.tru.com:8090/libs-release"
    }
mavenLocal()
}
    dependencies {
    //if jenkins build, refer common jar from Truven repository.
 if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) {
    compile group: 'com.tru.analyticsengine', name: 'common', version:'4.0.0.257'
    }else {
    //if local builds, refer common jar from local repository.
    compile group: 'com.tru.analyticsengine', name: 'common', version:'4.0.0.257'
    }
}



model {
  repositories {
    libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
      jdk {
        headers.srcDirs "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/win32",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/darwin",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/linux"
      }
    }
  }
}

model { 
  platforms {
    x64 { architecture "x86_64" }
    x86 { architecture "x86" }  
  }
}

model {
  components {
    main(NativeLibrarySpec) {
      sources {
        cpp {
          source {
            lib library: 'main', linkage: 'static'
            lib library: 'jdk', linkage: 'api'
            srcDir "src/main/c++/native"
            include "**/JniSupport.cpp"
            include "**/DiseaseStagingJni.cpp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def nativeHeadersDir = file("$buildDir/nativeHeaders")
//def compilePath = configurations.compile.resolve().collect {it.absolutePath}.join(";")
binaries.all {
    // Define toolchain-specific compiler and linker options
    if (toolChain in Gcc) {
        cppCompiler.args "-I${nativeHeadersDir}"
        cppCompiler.args "-g"
        linker.args  "-L../NativeJNI/src/main/resources/DSresources/DSLib"
        linker.args "-lds64"
}
}

//def nativeHeadersDir = file("$buildDir/nativeHeaders")
task nativeHeaders { 
    // def nativeHeadersDir = file("$buildDir/nativeHeaders")
     def outputFile = file("$nativeHeadersDir/DiseaseStagingJniWrapper.h") 
     def classes = [ 
             'com.truvenhealth.analyticsengine.common.diseasestaging.DiseaseStagingJniWrapper' 
                  ] 
     inputs.files sourceSets.main.output 
     inputs.property('classes', classes) 
     outputs.file outputFile 
     doLast { 
         outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs() 
         def compilePath = configurations.compile.resolve().collect {it.absolutePath}.join(":")
         println "Using Compile Path: ${compilePath}"
         exec { 
             executable org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getExecutable('javah') 
             args '-o', outputFile 
             args '-classpath', sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
             args classes 
         } 
     } 
 } 

             tasks.withType(CppCompile) { task -> 
                 task.dependsOn nativeHeaders 
             }
/*****************************
 * Packaging
 *****************************/

apply plugin: "maven"


// Workaround for Jenkins-Artifactory plugin not picking up the POM file

def pomFile = file("${buildDir}/libs/${archivesBaseName.toLowerCase()}-${version}.pom")
task newPom << {
  pom {
      project {
          groupId project.group
          artifactId project.name
          version project.version
          description = "Configuration Management Gradle Plugin"
      }
  }.writeTo(pomFile)
}
//Enabling  the install task for local build.
install.enabled = true

//for publishing to artifactory via jenkins
if(project.hasProperty('artifactoryPublish')) {
  artifactoryPublish {
    mavenDescriptor pomFile
  }
}else {
// publishing the artifactory to Maven local repository for local build.
uploadArchives{
repositories{
mavenLocal()
}
}
}
```

Error I am getting

```
    ../NativeJNI/src/main/resources/DSresources/DSLib/ds64.dll when searching for -lds64
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ../NativeJNI/src/main/resources/DSresources/DSLib/ds64.dll when searching for -lds64
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lds64
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0\libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthread
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthread
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ladvapi32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
     C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc

    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
       C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':linkMainSharedLibrary'.
    > Linker failed; see the error output for details.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to link 32 bit binary objects to a 64 bit executable. Why?

Comment: We are using the same in maven and it is working fine.The same configuration only build script is in maven.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above problem

> Windows: Server 2012 R2 Standard System  Type: 64-bit Operating System
>   Java jdk1.7.0_40  MinGw x86_64-5.2.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0
>   gradle: 2.3 version

I used the Mingw version MinGw x86_64-5.2.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0 and add the path of lib and some more changes.You can compare the above changes these changes

Below is my script and now able to create the dll file

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'
apply plugin: 'java'
//-- set the group for publishing
group = 'com.tru.analyticsengine'

/**
* Initializing GAVC settings
*/
def buildProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withInputStream { 
                stream -> buildProperties.load(stream) 
} 
//add the jenkins build version to the version
def env = System.getenv()

version = buildProperties.analyticsengineBuildVersion
println "${version}"

//name is set in the settings.gradle file
group = "com.tru.analyticsengine"
version = buildProperties.analyticsengineBuildVersion
println "Building ${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"

repositories {
    maven {
      url "http://art.tru.com:8000/libs-snapshot"
    }
     maven {
      url "http://art.tru.com:8000/libs-release"
    }
                maven {
      url "http://art.tru.com:8000/libs-alpha"
    }          
                mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
              if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) {
                   compile ([
                 "com.truv.analyticsengine:common:4.0.0.257"
                           ])
                }else{
                  compile ([
                  "com.truv.analyticsengine:common:4.0.0+"
                           ])
                }
}



model {
  repositories {
    libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
      jdk {
        headers.srcDirs "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/win32",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/darwin",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/linux"
      }
    }
  }
}

model { 
  platforms {
    x64 { architecture "x86_64" }
  }
}

model { 
  toolChains{
    gcc(Gcc){
          path "C:\\MINGW\\x86_64-5.2.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v4-
            rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
          eachPlatform() {
            cppCompiler.executable "g++.exe"
            cppCompiler.withArguments { args ->
                args.remove "-m32"
            }
            linker.withArguments { args ->
                args.remove "-m32"
            }
          }
     }
  }
}

model {
  components {
    main(NativeLibrarySpec) {
      sources {
        cpp {
          source {
            lib library: 'main', linkage: 'static'
            lib library: 'jdk', linkage: 'api'
            srcDir "src/main/c++/native"
            include "**/JniSupport.cpp"
            include "**/DiseaseStagingJni.cpp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def nativeHeadersDir = file("$buildDir/nativeHeaders")
binaries.all {
    // Define toolchain-specific compiler and linker options
    if (toolChain in Gcc) {
        cppCompiler.define "DLL_EXPORT"
        println "Include directory: ${nativeHeadersDir}"
        cppCompiler.args "-I${nativeHeadersDir}"
        cppCompiler.args "-g"
        linker.args '-shared'
        linker.args '-Lsrc/main/resources/DSresources/DSLib/'
        linker.args '-lds64' 
        }
}
task nativeHeaders { 
     def outputFile = file("$nativeHeadersDir/DiseaseStagingJniWrapper.h") 
     def classes = [ 
                'com.truvenhealth.analyticsengine.common.
          diseasestaging.DiseaseStagingJniWrapper' 
                  ] 
     inputs.files sourceSets.main.output 
     inputs.property('classes', classes) 
     outputs.file outputFile 
     doLast { 
         outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs() 
         def compilePath = configurations.compile.resolve().collect 
          {it.absolutePath}.join(";")
         println "Using Compile Path: ${compilePath}"
         exec { 
             executable 
          org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getExecutable('javah') 
             args '-o', outputFile 
             args '-classpath', compilePath
             args classes 
         } 
     } 
 } 

 tasks.withType(CppCompile) { task -> 
     task.dependsOn nativeHeaders 
 }

 apply plugin: "maven"


// Workaround for Jenkins-Artifactory plugin not picking up the POM file

def pomFile = file("${buildDir}\\libs\\${archivesBaseName.toLowerCase()}-    
      ${version}.pom")
task newPom << {
  pom {
      project {
          groupId project.group
          artifactId project.name
          version project.version
          description = "Configuration Management Gradle Plugin"
      }
  }.writeTo(pomFile)
}

// adding pom generation to taskGraph
build.dependsOn newPom

//disabling the install task since we're not using maven for real
install.enabled = false

//for publishing to artifactory via jenkins
if(project.hasProperty('artifactoryPublish')) {
  artifactoryPublish {
    mavenDescriptor pomFile
  }
}

task copyfile(type: Copy) {
  from "build\\binaries\\mainSharedLibrary\\main.dll"
  into 'build\\libs'
  rename { String fileName ->
    fileName.replace("main.dll", "NativeJNI-${project.version}.dll")
  }
}
build.dependsOn copyfile

artifacts {
   newPom
   }
```